# Split list into sublists at every occurrence of element starting with specific substring

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, formatting, nested-lists

I have a large list that contains a bunch of strings. I need to sort the elements of the original list into a nested list, determined by their placement in the list. In other words, I need to break the original list into sublists, where each sublist contains all elements that fall between an element starting with 'ABC', and then join them together as a nested list.

So the original list is:

```
all_results = ['ABCAccount', 'def = 0', 'gg = 0', 'kec = 0', 'tend = 1234567890', 'ert = abc', 'sed = target', 'id = sadfefsd3g3g24b24b', 'ABCAccount', 'def = 0', 'gg = 0', 'kec = 0', 'tend = NA', 'ert = abc', 'sed = source', 'id = sadfefsd3g3g24b24b', 'ABCAdditional', 'addkey = weds', 'addvalue = false', 'ert = abc', 'sed = target', 'id = sadfefsd3g3g24b24b', 'time_zone = EDT’]
```

And I need to return:

```
split_results = [['ABCAccount','def = 0', 'gg = 0', 'kec = 0', 'tend = 1234567890', 'ert = abc', 'sed = target', 'id = sadfefsd3g3g24b24b'],['ABCAccount', 'def = 0', 'gg = 0', 'kec = 0', 'tend = NA', 'ert = abc', 'sed = source', 'id = sadfefsd3g3g24b24b'],['ABCAdditional', 'addkey = weds', 'addvalue = false', 'ert = abc', 'sed = target', 'id = sadfefsd3g3g24b24b', 'time_zone = EDT’]]
```

I have tried the following:

```
split_results = [l.split(',') for l in ','.join(all_results).split('ABC')]
```

Comment: What process did you go through to produce your sample output?

Comment: think you are referring to the output being a nested list, that is fine too

Comment: It looks like you wanted a dict of dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work from your original list directly:

```
def make_split( lst ):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    r0 = []
    r1 = []
    for s in lst:
        if s.startswith("ABC"):
            if r1:
                r0.append(r1)
                r1 = []
        r1.append(s)
    return r0 + [r1]
```